# relevant big-endian OS and virtual machine for testing

Tags: testing, virtual-machine, endianness

I'd like to test some code to detect endianess issues. The trouble is that nowadays most computer architectures are little-endian, so I don't know which big-endian OS and virtual machine software to choose. I'd preferably like to compile my programs inside the virtual machine. How about middle-endian OSes?

Comment: there are some bi-endian architectures like ARM or modern MIPS. So you can run the code in your smartphones

Comment: Sure, but, I'd like to run the OSes in a virtual machine. I suppose qemu is one option for virtual machine software, but last time I tried using it, it was extremely slow (particularly with MIPS) and hard to setup.

Comment: you can try the android emulator. It uses qemu internally but has some features like cache so that subsequent startups are faster

Comment: I think android runs in le  mode

Comment: I think there's a way to change endianness in NDK

Comment: and... How does that help? I'll just compile code for wrong endianess.

Comment: why not? write native code that changes the endianness of the system, which is often defined by a flag or register. that way both big and little endian binaries can be run